# Global Variable to store password for postgres connection in PHP web application

Tags: php, database, postgresql, yii, yii2

I have a `yii2` framework php project in netbeans connected to `postgres database`.
In the config folder there is a file called `db.php` which contains the db credentials.

In some files (which is called by the controller) there is `pg_connect()` which connects to the database, so every time the project is deployed and the password of the db is different , need to change the password of the `pg_connect()` in all these files , is there a way to use `db.php` for the password or use a global variable to store the password.

Comment: in your db file create the connection object itself and then include it to other files. In that way you have to change only in your db file that's it. I don't know it's OK with the slandered of Yii Or not?

Comment: You mean create pg_connect() in the db.file and where ever its call it using require_once?

Comment: yes, exactly. create the connection in the file only and just pass that connection object to other files

Comment: `db.php` is the only file you need database credentials in. If you manually call methods to connect to database you are doing it wrong - that what `db` component is for.

Answer (score 0):

see the `\common\config\main.php` or `\common\config\main.php` for global config

```
'components' => [
  'db' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name', 
    'username' => 'db_username',
    'password' => 'db_password',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'schemaMap' => [
      'pgsql'=> [
        'class'=>'yii\db\pgsql\Schema',
        'defaultSchema' => 'public' //specify your schema here
      ]
    ], // PostgreSQL
],
```